# How to login with C# desktop application to ASP.NET-encrypted username/password

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, simplemembership, password-encryption

Okay so what I'm trying to do is create a desktop application in Visual C# that allows the user to log in using the same credentials as the ones with which they used to sign up to my MVC website. ASP.Net MVC creates an account controller which handles all the security and password hashing, and I basically want to be able to have the application check the password they enter in the desktop app against the one they created online.

The problem is there is no SimpleMembership for windows desktop apps so I have no idea how to handle the login and password encryption/decryption from the desktop app.

Once again, user creates username and password online, they must then be able to sign in with those credentials in a desktop app, checked against the same database.

Can anyone show me a way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Client Application Services to utilize existing ASP.NET membership provider as long as it implements Forms Authentication. For the detailed walkthrough please see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546195%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can also read through [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27670/Implementing-Application-Security-with-Client-Appl).

Comment: I have this in place in multiple WinForms applications and works flawelsly.

Comment: Will it work with MVC 4 web apps? Not just .net web services?

Comment: As long as you implement Forms Authentication in MVC apps it will.